# Reinstall windows 7 without disk

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, partitioning, partition-recovery

I want to reinstall windows 7 on my machine.

I read this from http://www.pcworld.com/article/2364269/how-to-reinstall-windows-like-a-pro.html

> Windows, it’s up to the PC manufacturer to provide a recovery partition or recovery discs. Most manufacturers don’t include Windows installation discs with their computers.
>
> partition, run your manufacturer’s recovery tool to reinstall Windows. On many PCs, you’ll have to press a key during the boot process to access the recovery tool. This key may be displayed on your screen. It should also be printed in your computer’s manual.
>
> disc, you can also insert it in your computer’s optical drive and boot from it to begin reinstalling Windows. You’ll end up with the manufacturer’s like-new Windows system on your drive.

**Do I have to find a windows 7 on piratebay in order to install it now?** I don't have a windows disk.

Comment: You need a disk so download the ISO linked on this website and use it

Answer (score 3):

If you have a valid Windows product key, you can legally download an official, untouched ISO. Here are some links:

- http://www.howtogeek.com/186775/how-to-download-windows-7-8-and-8.1-installation-media-legally/
- http://www.techverse.net/download-windows-7-iso-x86-x64-microsofts-official-servers/

You'll need the key to activate Windows after the installation procedure.

Comment: I think he can also download official trial version from microsoft and just activate it with genuine key.

Comment: Not any version though. If you have a CoA for windows 7 home then you need to download windows 7 home. The key will not work on an other windows 7 version.  (Assuming you do not use the ei.cfg trick).

Comment: Also. A trial version? Are you referring to non-trial full versions which give you up to 30 days to activate?